# When do we need to mention Id explicitly in SOQL querry

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

I heard that although the Id field always comes implicitly in SOQL query result, there is a specific scenario where we have to include the Id field while querying records. Can someone please tell me what is that scenario is?

Comment: Where did you hear this? Could you give a little more detail as to what your scenario is? At the moment your question looks more like an exam/homework question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no "benefit" as such by including it when your SOQL contains one or more other fields being queried as it is always returned in Apex queries, whether it is specified in the query or not.

The only time you may want to specify the Id field if it is the only field you’re retrieving because you have to specify at least one field i.e `SELECT Id FROM Contact`.

`SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact` and `SELECT Name FROM Contact` are equivalent statements.